# Prove that $(AB)C = A(BC)=ABC$ for ideals $A, B, C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is from Theorem 2.6 (iii) of Hungerford. 
My Try:
$$(AB)C=\sum_kc_k\sum_{k_i}a_{k_i}b_{k_i}$$
$$A(BC)=\sum_ka_k\sum_{k_i}b_{k_i}c_{k_i}$$
Now how can I prove they are same?

Comment: It is much more handy to work with definition of the product of ideals in terms of generators.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two expressions you have written down are equivalent - they both run over all finite sums of elements of the form $abc$, where $a\in A,b\in B,c\in C$.

Explicitly, you have:
$$
(AB)C=\left\{\sum_k c_k\sum_{i_k} a_{i_k}b_{i_k}\right\}\\
A(BC)=\left\{\sum_k a_k\sum_{i_k} b_{i_k}c_{i_k}\right\}
$$

Now define
$$
ABC=\left\{\sum_k a_kb_kc_k\right\}
$$
Try and show that
$$
(AB)C=ABC\\
A(BC)=ABC
$$

Comment: I think $$\sum_kc_k\sum_{i_k}a_{i_k}b_{i_k} = \sum_ja_jb_jc_j$$ since each product has the same form. So they are equal. Is this correct?

Comment: @zed111 What you've written doesn't really make sense, but I think you're close to the right answer.  What are $c_k,a_{i_k},b_{i_k},a_j,b_j,c_j$?

Comment: Do I have to show that the two are equal by showing $(AB)C\subseteq(ABC) and (ABC) \subseteq (AB)C$? i.e. for every summmation of one form there exists a summation of another form which is equal to it

Comment: @zed111 Exactly.